# R, ggarrange when increase the number of plots, the plots get flatten. How to increase the final image?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, r-markdown, size

I'm using ggarrange() to Arrange multiple ggplot objects on a page. I'm using Rmarkdown.

```
    pguecof <- ggarrange(plotlist = plot_list,
          ncol = 2, nrow = ceiling(countries/2),
                  heights=c(1,1), widths = c(1,1))

annotate_figure(pguecof,
                top = text_grob("Equilibria in each of the simulation"), 
color = "Black", face = "bold", size = 14))
```

As I increase the number of plots in ggarrange, the plots get flatten. In the pdf I obtain, both final images have the same hight. 
How do I do to keep the original proportion/size? The final picture can be bigger in height.
Thanks